# Excel date format from "Jun 05 2023" to "05-Jun-2023"

Tags: excel

Sorry if the question is stupid :(

How can I easily do this in Excel. Thanks in advance

format from "Jun 05 2023" to "05-Jun-2023"

simple format cells didnt help

Are there any inner tools in Excel? Or I need to use some formulas

Comment: I dont need exact date cell format, just need to make it look like this

Comment: If format did not change what you are seeing then the date is stored as a text string and not a true date.   Which means you will need to parse the string with a formula in another column to create the proper date format for excel to know it is a date

Comment: Did you make sure the cells [actually contain dates](https://superuser.com/q/299437/52365)?

Comment: `=TEXTJOIN("-",,INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(A1," "),,{2,1,3}))`

Comment: or better yet: `=--TEXTJOIN(" ",,INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(A1," "),,{2,1,3}))` then format the cell `dd-mmm-yyyy`

Comment: Have you tried doing this way, `=DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",", ",2))` ? And format the return value as `dd-mm-yyyy`

Comment: I just found out, `Text To Columns` can also work, but if there are non printable characters or some annoying characters then it might won't work, it totally depends on your data.

Comment: I tried to change it to date in Text To columns, the type was changed from general to date but the form didnt changed. Its still "Jun 05 2023". I copied this dates as a text i think, and now i need to change it as a "05-Jun-2023" to save as ASC file for another soft

Comment: Then try the formula posted by @ScottCraner sir or the one i have posted. Try that and let us know.

Comment: You are not going to be able to do this in place without vba.  Without vba you will need to use a helper column then copy paste the values back over the original column.